# Errors on my loop for my program

Tags: python, python-2.7, printing

```
'''
#Temperature Converter
#Author: Coleton Ishmael
#Class: ICS 3U
#Date: 10/29/2015
'''
```

I need to create a program that calculates the temperature of three different systems which are Celsius, Kelvin and Fahrenheit. I am having some problems with this code below as it isn't operating how I think it should be. Have a look below and the problem that I am having is listed at the bottom where the code is ended!

```
#Fahrenheit to Celsuis and Kelvin
typeofconversion= (raw_input(" Would you like to convert Fahrenheit (type F), Celsius (type C) or Kelvin (type K)?"))

if typeofconversion== " F":
    statement= (raw_input( " What is the temperature in Fahrenheit?"))
    fcconversion= (int(statement)-32)*5.0/9
    fkconversion= (int(statement)-32)/1.8000 +273.15
    print " In Celsuis, that is:"
    print round(fcconversion,2)
    print " In Kelvin, that is:"
    print round (fkconversion,2)
if typeofconversion== " C":
    #Celsius to Fahrenheit and Kelvin
    statement= (raw_input( " What is the temperature in Celsuis?"))
    cfconversion= (int(statement) *9) / 5 + 32
    ckconversion=(int(statement)+273)
    print " In Fahrenheit, that is:"
    print round(cfconversion,2)
    print " In Kelvin, that is:"
    print round(ckconversion,2) 
elif typeofconversion== " K":
    #Kelvin to Celsius and Fahrenheit
    statement= (raw_input( " What is the temperature in Kelvin?"))
    kcconversion= (int(statement) *9) / 5 + 32
    kfconversion=(int(statement)- 273.15)* 1.8000+ 32.00
    print " In Celsius that is:"
    print round(kcconversion,2)
    print "In Fahrenheit that is:"
    print round(kfconversion,2)    

#Conversions defined
def fcconversion (fcconversion):
    result=""

'''
Main Program
'''

# Celsius to Fahrenheit, and Kelvin Loop
for i in range(2):
    typeofconversion= (raw_input(" Would you like to convert Fahrenheit (type F), Celsius (type C) or Kelvin (type K)?"))
    if typeofconversion== " F":
        statement= (raw_input( " What is the temperature in Fahrenheit?"))
        fcconversion=(int(statement)-32)*5.0/9
        fkconversion=(int(statement)-32)/1.8000 +273.15
        print " In Celsuis, that is:"
        print round(fcconversion,2)
        print " In Kelvin, that is:"
        print round (fkconversion,2)
    if typeofconversion==" C":
        statement= (raw_input( " What is the temperature in Celsuis?"))
        cfconversion=(int(statement) *9) / 5 + 32
        ckconversion=(int(statement)+273)
        print " In Fahrenheit, that is:"
        print round(cfconversion,2)
        print " In Kelvin, that is:"
        print round(ckconversion,2)
```

I've been encountering an error on where I try to do my loop for the Celsius part of the code. It is saying fcconversion is not defined which it is. I'm wondering what is wrong with my code!

Comment: `fcconversion` is only defined if `typeofconversion == " F"`.

Comment: How would I get rid of the error?

Comment: Don't try to print `fcconversion` if the user entered "C".

Comment: But in the program that's not under there do I take everything out? What I mean by everything is fcconversion under F?

Comment: The four print statements are **not** indented underneath `typeofconversion == " F"`.

Comment: It should be a yellow print not a purple one right? This is for Python 2.7 btw

Comment: It should loop three times and the user has the choice of what to choose and still doesn't work right.

Comment: Solved it just now thanks John Gordon for a little better help.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(3):
    typeofconversion= (raw_input(" Would you like to convert Fahrenheit (type F), Celsius (type C) or Kelvin (type K)?"))
    if typeofconversion== " F":
        statement= (raw_input( " What is the temperature in Fahrenheit?"))
        fcconversion=(int(statement)-32)*5.0/9
        fkconversion=(int(statement)-32)/1.8000 +273.15
        print " In Celsuis, that is:"
        print round(fcconversion,2)
        print " In Kelvin, that is:"
        print round (fkconversion,2)


#Fahrenheit to Celsius and Kelvin Loop
    if typeofconversion==" C":
        statement= (raw_input( " What is the temperature in Celsuis?"))
        cfconversion=(int(statement) *9) / 5 + 32
        ckconversion=(int(statement)+273)
        print " In Fahrenheit, that is:"
        print round(cfconversion,2)
        print " In Kelvin, that is:"
        print round(ckconversion,2)

#Kelvin to Celsius and Fahrenheit Loop
    if typeofconversion== " K":
        statement= (raw_input( " What is the temperature in Kelvin?"))
        kcconversion= (int(statement) *9) / 5 + 32
        kfconversion=(int(statement)- 273.15)* 1.8000+ 32.00
        print " In Celsius that is:"
        print round(kcconversion,2)
        print "In Fahrenheit that is:"
        print round(kfconversion,2)
```

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and edit your Answer accordingly. It is no use as of now.